# Adding multiple classes in AJS and bootstrap apps

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons, ng-class

I want to enable and disable (hide and show, with opacity) a glyphicon in my Angular Js app. I use ng-class for enabling and disabling click on glyphicon. So how do i add class(common - glyphicon) in my html?

My requirement is something like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 divfilter">


                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter ng-class="{'imgOpaque':!apply.isfilterCickable?,'imgCl':apply.isfilterCickable}"></span>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

if apply.isfilterCickable=true, it will apply class 'imgCl' otherwise it will apply class 'imgOpaque'.

```
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" ng-class="apply.isfilterCickable?'imgCl':'imgOpaque'"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary operator:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" ng-class="{ apply.isfilterCickable ? 'imgCl' : 'imgOpaque' }"></span>
```

This should give you some more info:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass